# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '.'.'

Tags: sql, json, .net

I try to something about .Net Core Wep API with SQL. I got the incorrect syntax near '.''.'

ı use postman for api and try whether it came or not with json.

in appsettings.json code;

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "EmployeeAppCon": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EmployeeDB; Integrated Security=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

And ı tried get, post method but ı got an error in here with Uptade method ;

```
[HttpPut]
        public JsonResult Put(Department dep)
        {
            string query = @"
                       Uptade dbo.Department set 
                       DepartmentName='"+dep.DepartmentName+@"'
                       where DepartmentId="+dep.DepartmentId+@"
                       ";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeAppCon");
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                {
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    table.Load(myReader); ;
                    myReader.Close();
                    myCon.Close();
                }

            }
            return new JsonResult("Uptade Successfull");

        }
```

Where is my fault please help me thanks a lot?

Comment: Use parameters in your query to resolve your issue as well as any injection issues. Also the word is Update an not Uptade

Comment: The department name could contain single quote and mass up your SQL. This also prone to SQL injection.

Comment: very minor, but: `new JsonResult("Uptade Successfull")` [sic] is odd... because: that's not JSON

Comment: (just to add: *in addition to* the bit where concatenation causes errors, and opens you up to SQL injection - it also causes problems with i18n/l10n (in particular dates and numbers), and is suboptimal re query plan re-use; so: fundamentally "always use parameters" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a problem with concatenation in the SQL; long story short: **never ever** concatenate input into SQL; the *correct* operation is more like:

```sql
update dbo.Department
set DepartmentName=@name
where DepartmentId=@id
```

where `@name` and `@id` are parameters.

Then you would use `myCommand.Parameters.Add(...)` to include those two parameters *and their names/values*, and use `ExecuteNonQuery` (not `ExecuteReader`).

However! It would be much simpler to get [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) (free etc) to do all the hard work for us, then we can just do:

```cs
using var myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource); // don't even need to open it
myCon.Execute(@"
update dbo.Department
set DepartmentName=@name
where DepartmentId=@id",
    new { name = dep.DepartmentName, id = dep.DepartmentId });
```

where the `new {...}` here defines our named parameters with values.