# try to insert row to sql server database using c# ado,net

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to insert a row in a SQL Server database using Ado.Net in a Console Application
I am reading input from keyboard....

here is my code:

```cs
private void InsertStudents(string con)
{      
   SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(con);
   SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

   int id               = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   string     firstName = Console.ReadLine();
   string      lastName = Console.ReadLine();
   DateTime dateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
   double   tuitionFees = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

   string sql = "$insert into product (ID,FirstName,LastName,DateOfBirth,TuitionFees) values {id}, {firstName}, {lastName}, {dateOfBirth}, {tuitionFees})";
   try
   {
        Connection.Open();
        adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, Connection);
        adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(" 1 Row inserted!");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
   }
}
```

my problem is that the compiler reads my interpolated string as a string but not recognising the columns as variables...it reads the whole line as a single string.
what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is very important: **do not** use interpolated strings with SQL; it is **bad in every way**:

- security: SQL injection
- performance: query plan reuse
- reliability: brittleness with reserved symbols like `'`
- correctness: i18n/l10n (i.e. formatting) issues - especially relevant for the `DateTime` value (date of birth; is "07/11/2020" the 7th of November? or the 11th of July?) - but also the tuition fees amount (in "123,456", is the comma a decimal separator (France et al)? or a group separator?)

The correct approach is *parameters*. Always.

So, SQL like:

```sql
insert into product (ID,FirstName,LastName,DateOfBirth,TuitionFees)
values (@id, @firstName, @lastName, @dateOfBirth, @tuitionFees)
```

And to do that, *either* learn about ADO.NET parameters, or: use a tool like [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) that simplifies it:

```cs
int id = ...
string firstName = ...
string lastName =  ...
DateTime dateOfBirth = ...
double   tuitionFees = ...

using var conn = new SqlConnection(con); // Dapper will deal with the open/close
conn.Execute(@"
insert into product (ID,FirstName,LastName,DateOfBirth,TuitionFees)
values (@id, @firstName, @lastName, @dateOfBirth, @tuitionFees)",
    new { id, firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, tuitionFees });
```

Also, final note: do not use `double` for currency; use `decimal`. `double` is not suitable for currency amounts.

Answer (score 0):

You have placed the dollar sign inside the string, instead of in front of it.  It should be:

```
string sql = $"insert into product (ID,FirstName,LastName,DateOfBirth,TuitionFees) values {id}, {firstName}, {lastName}, {dateOfBirth}, {tuitionFees})";
```

Comment: this is **actively harmful advice** - exactly the same as I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64982828/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-incorrect-syntax-near/64982926#comment114885731_64982887)