# how can I convert a c# variable of type double to sql float

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using a variable type of double in c#
and I want to insert it in an sql row in sql server.

I read the variable from keyboard (implementing a console application)
the problem that I understand that C# has different format than sql server...

e.g. the number 12,34 in c# is equivalent to 12.34 in sql server...

how can I make the conversion so to insert it to the row I want?

Comment: Prefer [parameterized query](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx).

Comment: If you're using a parameterised query to do the insert then this will not cause a problem. The types 'underneath the hood' are compatible

Comment: can you show some code of what you're trying. The double or float variables don't have a `,`or `.`in it, it's just the visual representation, a matter of string formatting and culture settings

Comment: what's up with your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64983921/try-to-insert-row-to-sql-server-database-using-c-sharp-ado-net)? You already got the same advice there as in the comments above. Marc Gravell gave a good answer there, which also covered your format problem for float/double values.

Comment: if anything is still unclear in the given answers to your other question,  write a comment under the answer to just ask for clarification instead of asking a new question.

Comment: In both C# and SQL Server, numeric types do not _have_ a format. If you use parameterized queries and the right parameter types, the format you _see_ should not matter. If you're concatenating strings then the format may make a difference.